# How to get the cordova 2.9.1 jar for phonegap 2.9.1 for android development

Tags: android, cordova

I have download the Phonegap 2.9.1 and extract the zip and I looked into the lib folder and then the android it doesnot contain the cordova jar.

So can anyone tell me how to get the import the cordova jar to my project.

Answer (score 1):

go to the `framework` folder and run `ant`, that should create the `cordova-2.9.1.jar`

but you don't really need it, if you go to the `bin` folder and run `./create projectFolder com.package.test projectName`, a new android project will be created and it will include the `cordova-2.9.1.jar` in the lib folder